# Can I authorize users in my application (JWT) without front-end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, axios, authorization

So, I am new at node and decided to create a user authentication/authorization system. Btw, I am using ejs as view engine and not any front-end framework. Everything works when I use postman to check API. Users are registered, tokens are generated while logging in and most importantly authorization also works when I manually put generated token in header (using postman). But how could I extract those tokens and put them in headers without postman? I saw some implementations using axios, fetch etc. But all of them were using front-end frameworks to do that.

[Logging in users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELYUA.png)

[Accessing protected route without token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZPlK.png)

[Accessing protected route with token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlRTx.png)

**UPDATE:**

So the problem was in passport.authenticate() method and I added my personal verification method to extract cookies specifically.

```
  const verifyJWT = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const signedToken = req.cookies.jwt;

  if (signedToken) {
    jwt.verify(
      signedToken,
      config.PRIV_KEY,
      { algorithms: ["RS256"] },
      (err: any, decodedToken: any) => {
        if (err) {
          // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
          console.log(decodedToken);
          next();
        }
      }
    );
  } else {
    res.send("Unathorized");
  }
};
```

Comment: If you do not want a front-end framework, how do you intend to make the requests with the token in the `Authorization: Bearer` header? You cannot use an HTML `<form>` with that header, will you use the Javascript [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) method?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use frameworks but you do need to use javascript. Whatever you do with postman you can do using `fetch` or `axios`, you can save the tokens in your cookie.

Comment: Do you have any reference of how could I achieve that? 
My tokens are saved in cookies whenever users try to log in - Name: Authorization, Value: Bearer%20token... But when user is redirected to a protected route (or any other route) cookies aren't present anymore.

Comment: @Emiya, but I see no cookies in your Postman screenshots. I only see the `Authorization` _header_.